# My external HDD stopped working

Tags: hard-drive

A friend of my mine pulled the external HDD USB cable when it was in use. It is not getting detected now (wouldn't even spin). I took it out of its external case and plugged it directly into my computer and still nothing.

I replaced the controller board with a brand new one I ordered online, the drive spins up but nothing still.

On, a side note when I plugged it directly into my computer it booted into some kind of recovery I have never seen, displaying a blue line on top of the screen and in the middle of the screen it said `wait...` but nothing happens after 20 min.

It's a WD5000BPVT if that helps. How to get it back to working state?

Comment: Sounds like the drive is dead since you have tried literally everything most people would do

Comment: So if most people would have done this what would the other percentage of people do?

Comment: What if I had one of the exact same drive and carefully placed the disk(s) into the working one?

Comment: The minute you attempt to do that the disks will be damaged beyond repair you would need a clean room.

Comment: If the data is worth that much send it to a recovery company which will attempt to transfer the platters to another HDD and read the data but no guarantees

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like your last best hope, but you have to be so extremely careful that I'm not sure if the disks are going to survive it.

So when you plug it in it spins, but your computer doesn't even recognize it? Just to be sure: your usb-ports are ok? Because it should detect the controller if you replaced it.

Comment: I tried every usb port and of course tried to plug it directly into the computer via sata/power cable. Yes, I too expected it to at least show up with something beings I replaced the controller board. But no, computer didn't even flinch. Side note: you do believe it will work but with extreme care, but of course it might not survive that process?

Comment: if attempt this suggestion you will damage your hardware.